# jQuery Delete dialog does not work

Tags: asp.net, jquery-dialog, itemtemplate

I have a page with a GridView that has `Delete`button for each row.
When clicking the button, I display jQuery`dialog with`Confirm`and`Cancel` option.

This is the `ItemTeplate` for `Delete` button:

```
<ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Button ID="delete" runat="server" CommandName="delete" Text"Delete" CssClass="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-butt-text-only" OnClientClick="return ShowDeleteConf('Are you sure you want to delete?');" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

This is the function:

```
function ShowDeleteConf(message) {

    $(function () {
        $('#deleteConf').html(message);
        $('#deleteConf').dialog({
           title: "Delete Confirmation",
           buttons: {
              Cancel: function () {
                  $(this).dialog('close');
              },
              Confirm: function () {
                  return true;
              }
           }
      });
   });
}
```

When I click `Delete` button, the dialog is displayed for 1 second and is closed by itself, so I cannot event press any button.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try removing the $(function () {}); from around the code in ShowDeleteConf.

Comment: Nop, still the same problem